# How to customize lxpanel/menu on lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, lxpanel

Does anyone know "how to add item PCManFM or some programs likes terminal, anjuta or more programs on panel menu". The configuration file located on ~/.config/lxpanel/lubuntu/panels, but I dont know how to add this item . Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you question correctly you want to add quick launchers to the panel

If you right click the panel and click panel settings, a window called 'Panel Preferences' should appear, click the 'Panel Applets' tab, there should be 'Application Launch Bar' in the list ( if not click 'Add' to add it ), highlight it by clicking on it and then click the 'Edit' button on the left, this should bring up another window where you can add panel items from the right hand side to the left where they will be now on you panel.